# Disable quartz logging

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

How can I disable Quartz logging?
Quartz is printing INFO statements on my console.
I have tried to disable it with the following statement in log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.org.quartz=ALL, CONSOLE
```

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/63063/open-source/HowTo-Disable-Logging-Output-classes

Comment: Maybe `log4j.logger.org.quartz=WARN, CONSOLE`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possible duplicate with [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java).

Try this out:

```
  log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF
```

Comment: In the future, please flag question which are duplicates instead of answering. Thanks!

Comment: If you use a Maven project and you don't have the properties file, create `log4j.properties` under `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my log4j.xml file worked!

```
 <logger name="org.quartz" additivity="false">
     <level value="ERROR"/>
 </logger>
```