# Turning off Quartz job logging

Tags: logging, quartz-scheduler, log4j

In my application, quartz job is scheduled as soon as the application is deployed. I have two log files `home-log-search.log` and `home-log-app.log`, both for specific logging. Search log file is only to log the visitor's IP and rest all logging (exception, debug info) are logged in App log file.

The problem which i am facing is, the default Quartz statements are getting logged in `home-log-search.log` file which is not required.

How can i disable that logging? Setting level to **OFF** doesn't worked. I also followed [disable quartz logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421353/disable-quartz-logging) but that also didn't helped.

Below is my *log4j.properties*

```
# properties file for testing logging service
log4j.debug = true
# Set root category priority to DEBUG and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, searchLogger

log4j.appender.searchLogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.searchLogger.File=${catalina.home}/logs/home-search-log.log
log4j.appender.searchLogger.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.logger.searchLogger.quartz=OFF, searchLogger

log4j.appender.searchLogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.searchLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.searchLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-4p %m%n

log4j.logger.appLogger=DEBUG, appLogger
log4j.additivity.appLogger = false
log4j.appender.appLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appLogger.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.appLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c : %m%n
log4j.appender.appLogger.File=${catalina.home}/logs/home-app-log.log
```

Also below is my job scheduling class

```
public class SubscriptionNotificationJobScheduler {

/**
 * config bundle
 */
private static ResourceBundle configBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");


public SubscriptionNotificationJobScheduler(String path) throws ParseException, SchedulerException{

    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName(SubscriptionConstants.JOB_NAME);
    job.setJobClass(SubscriptionNotificationJob.class);

    JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
    map.put("contextPath", path);
    job.setJobDataMap(map);

    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    trigger.setName(SubscriptionConstants.TRIGGER_NAME);
    trigger.setCronExpression(configBundle.getString("monday.cron.trigger"));

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable logging for the quartz java package, that is `org.quartz.*`

It looks as though you have misconfigured log4j with this line

`log4j.logger.searchLogger.quartz=OFF, searchLogger`

Instead it should read

`log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF`