# Where does Spring's quartz keep its log files?

Tags: spring, logging, quartz-scheduler

Does anybody know where quartz keeps its logs by default?

I tried to search for log files, but I cannot seem to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz logs using the log4j api, so you you can adjust its logging using your log framework (typically log4j or logback). Configuring logging is out of scope for this question, but for some basic information see these other StackOverflow posts:

[Disable quartz logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421353/disable-quartz-logging)

[Turning off Quartz job logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102822/turning-off-quartz-job-logging)