# How to disable logger in quartz library jar

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Currently using Quartz job to schedule the daily job for one of my module. Quartz log is always appending to my application log file every time. I am handling the quartz exception seperately in my application. I don't want quartz debugger log to add to my application log file. How can i prevent this?

I used the below log config xml file. It is not working.

```
<appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="ApplicationLog">
    <param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex"/>
    <param value="200MB" name="MaxFileSize"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %p - [%C -> %M() - >%L] %-450m%n" name="ConversionPattern" />
    </layout>
</appender> 

 <logger name="org.quartz" additivity="false" level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="ApplicationLog" />
</logger>
<root> 
<priority value ="debug" />
<appender-ref ref="ApplicationLog"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable quartz logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421353/disable-quartz-logging)

Answer (score 0):

log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF

for more clarity please visit

[Disable quartz logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421353/disable-quartz-logging)