# Disabling logs created by log4j while calling an external Webservice

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have log4j in my JAVA application and when I call an external WebService, I have many debug logs of this webservice. Can I disable these logs ?

(I want of course keep all the other logs of my application and I disable only the one for Webservice call method)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For the classic log4j (1.2):

Via [Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Configuration)

> Suppose we are no longer interested in seeing the output of any
>   component belonging to the com.foo package. The following
>   configuration file shows one possible way of achieving this.
>
> ```
> # ...Irrelevant config...
>
> # Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
> log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
> ```

If you want to do this programmatically, refer to the earlier part of the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

Set level to OFF (instead of DEBUG, INFO, ....)

Comment: It will disable logging for all my application, how can I disable it only for a method (calling webservice method)