# Start configuration snippet for log4j2.properties?

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm looking for a `log4j2.properties` snippet that I can drop in to `src/test/resources` just to make the `No logj2 configuration file found` warning disappear.  If it contains other useful sample like configuration examples that's great as well.

Basically I'm looking for the `.properties` version of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %c{1.} [%t] %-5level} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Log4J Output in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java)

Comment: Please remove the duplicate notification.  I'm trying to silcence the warning only, while keeping the trace logging going to the console.

Comment: Edit the body of the question to indicate why it is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this should do the trick.

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = target/logs/test.log

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LogFile
appender.file.fileName = ${filename}
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = LogFile
```

Here is a log4j2.xml that I actually use in some of my unit tests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="ERROR">
  <properties>
    <property name="LOG_DIR">target/logs</property>
  </properties>
  <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5level # %class.%method %m%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="log4j" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/log4j.txt" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/archive/log4j.txt.%d{yyyyMMdd_HH}-%i">
      <PatternLayout>
        <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="%d [%t] %-5p %X{loginId, userId, ipAddress, corpAcctNumber} %C{1.}.%M:%L - %m%n">
          <PatternMatch key="FLOW" pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %X{loginId, userId, ipAddress, corpAcctNumber} -------- %C{1.}.%M:%L %msg --------%n"/>
        </MarkerPatternSelector>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="30 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="log4j" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```