# Turn off SLF4J from Console using DBUnit

Tags: java, slf4j, dbunit, log4j

I'm using DBUnit to run some tests in Java. I have put this in my code before I kick off the test:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.dbunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Which stops logging to the console in Eclipse. However when I run this jar from a windows console I see this string of text print out to the console over and over again

```
SLF4J: org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.StringDataType
SLF4J: org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.StringDataType
SLF4J: org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.StringDataType
SLF4J: org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTable
SLF4J: org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData
```

What can I do to get this to stop printing to the console?

Current Log4j config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.file.File=test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.logger.org.dbunit=ERROR
```

Comment: Which logger implementation do you use? Most allow to add a log config file that shuts off logging.

Comment: Its log4j, I have a log4j.properties file. But w/e combination of configs I use doesn't seem to stop it: Adding my current config to the question.

Comment: By setting the log level to `OFF` you should disable all logging (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571960/disabling-log4j-output-in-java). If this does not work, there is something other wrong with your logger setup. And indeed the log messages don't look like they are coming from log4j.